# why df.loc[0][0] giving first second and not the first in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-science

i am working on this project after a while and i am confused because i dont know why df.loc[0][0] is giving second row and not the first.
below is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
#import numpy as np
import os
import time


def get_month():
    c_m = time.strftime("%b")
    return c_m
    
def get_full_month():
    c_m = time.strftime("%B")
    return c_m

def get_year():
    c_y = time.strftime("%Y")
    return c_y

def get_day():
    day = datetime.now().strftime('%A')
    return day

def get_date():
    currentdate = datetime.now().day
    return currentdate

def update_day(df):
    df.loc[0][get_date()] = get_day()

def update_date(df):
    df.loc[1][get_date()] = get_date()

def update_marks(df):
    df[str(get_date())].replace({"0": "3", "0": "3"}, inplace=True)

def create_file(df):
    df.to_csv(f"{get_month()}-{get_year()}.csv", index=False)

def update_last(df):
    thirty_day = ["April","June","September","November"]
    #print(get_month())
    if get_full_month() in thirty_day:
        print("update_last")
        if "31" in df.columns:
            df.pop("31")

def update_sunday(df):
    if get_day() == "saturday":
        df[str(int(get_date())+1)].replace({"0": "3", "0": "3"}, inplace=True)
        df.loc[0][get_date+1()] = "Sunday"


def update_late(df):

    late_teacher_numbers = input("how many teachers are late(TYPE IN NUMBERS) : ")
    if late_teacher_numbers.isnumeric:
        for f in range(int(late_teacher_numbers)):
            all_teacher = df.iloc[2:,0].tolist()
            #print(all_teacher)
            print("TEACHERS CODE LIST:\n ")
            teachers_code_list = [print(f"CODE NO   {i}   =    TEACHER NAME   {v}") for i,v in enumerate(all_teacher)]
            user = input("enter teacher code : ")
            if user.isnumeric():
                opt = input("decide between \"LATE\" \n \"V.LATE\" \n \"ABSENT\" \nenter option : ")
                opt = opt.upper()
                if opt == "LATE":
                    opt = 2
                    df.at[int(user)+2, str(get_date())] = opt
                elif opt == "V.LATE":
                    opt = 1
                    df.at[int(user)+2, str(get_date())] = opt
                elif opt == "ABSENT":
                    opt = 0
                    df.at[int(user)+2, str(get_date())] = opt

            else:
                print("PLEASE TYPE CODE FROM TEACHERS CODE LIST\n THANKYOU")
                print('PLEASE TRY AGAIN')
                main()
    else:
        print("PLEASE USE NUMERIC VALUES")
        main()

def update_csv(df):
    df.to_csv(f"{get_month()}-{get_year()}.csv", index=False)

def check_file(file):
    if os.path.isfile(file):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def main():
    file_name = f"{get_month()}-{get_year()}.csv"
    if check_file(file_name) == False:
        df = pd.read_csv("reg format.csv")
        create_file(df)
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
        update_date(df)
        update_day(df)
        update_last(df)
        update_marks(df)
        update_sunday(df)
        late = input("If any teacher is late \npress \"Y\" else 
 press\"N\" : ")
        if late.upper() == "Y":
            update_late(df)
            update_csv(df)
            print("ATTENDACE SHEET OF THIS MONTH : ")
            print(df)
            print("TODAYS ATTENDANCE SHEET")
            print(df[str(get_date())])
        else:
            print("ATTENDACE SHEET OF THIS MONTH : ")
            print(df)
            print("TODAYS ATTENDANCE SHEET")
            print(df[str(get_date())])
    else:
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
        update_last(df)
        update_date(df)
        update_day(df)
        update_marks(df)
        #update_sunday(df)
        late = input("If any teacher is late \npress \"Y\" else 
 press\"N\" : ")
        if late.upper() == "Y":
            update_late(df)
            update_csv(df)
            print("ATTENDACE SHEET OF THIS MONTH : ")
            print(df)
            print("TODAYS ATTENDANCE SHEET")
            print(df[str(get_date())])
        else:
            print("ATTENDACE SHEET OF THIS MONTH : ")
            print(df)
            print("TODAYS ATTENDANCE SHEET")
            print(df[str(get_date())])
main()
```

[reg format file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kmCRV3LfG7t57b8ZL3NycmMXqa1KZpQq/view?usp=sharing)
for suppose

```
def update_day(df):
df.loc[0][get_date()] = get_day()
```

this updates the second row but not the first
I want to update the first row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check your column/row names as that might interfere with the results returned by [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html). Remember that `loc` is a label-based indexer, while [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) is position-based.

Therefore, for the first cell in the first row, you can use `iloc`, as follows:

```py
df.iloc[0, 0]
```

To get the entire first row, you can use either:

```py
df.iloc[0, :]
```

Or more succintly:

```py
df.iloc[0]
```

Comment: I dont know why but this error is coming  
KeyError: 0

Comment: @S.Uzair Please see the updated answer and explanations. Hope this helps!